# How to use manual focus in Android CameraX?

Tags: android, focus, setfocus, android-camerax

I am trying to do manual focus on CameraX the same as I do in Camera2 API

in Camera2 API I use the following code

```
final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE); 

captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF); 

captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, mLensFocusDistance);
```

Can manual focus be done in android camera X?  If so how

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you figure out how to achieve this in CameraX?

Comment: no camera X is currently unable to https://groups.google.com/a/android.com/forum/#!searchin/camerax-developers/focus%7Csort:date/camerax-developers/ySfolLe_AS8/hOhHRViaCgAJ

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a way to use manual focus in cameraX by accessing low-level camera2 API with [`Camera2Interop.Extender`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/camera2/interop/Camera2Interop.Extender#Extender(androidx.camera.core.ExtendableBuilder%3CT%3E)). You should set two extra options to preview builder like this:

```
void setFocusDistance(ExtendableBuilder<?> builder, float distance) {
    Camera2Interop.Extender extender = new Camera2Interop.Extender(builder);
    extender.setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF);
    extender.setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, distance);
}
```

And use it when building your cameraX preview request:

```
float focusDistance = 0F; // example: infinite focus
Preview.Builder previewBuilder = new Preview.Builder();
setFocusDistance(previewBuilder, focusDistance);
preview = previewBuilder.build();
preview.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.getSurfaceProvider());
```

Note that you may also set other camera2 CaptureRequest options in this manner.

---

Here's how to find the LENS_INFO_MINIMUM_FOCUS_DISTANCE (often a value around 10f):

```
theCamera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(...
CameraCharacteristics camChars = Camera2CameraInfo
   .extractCameraCharacteristics(theCamera.getCameraInfo());
float discoveredMinFocusDistance = camChars
   .get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_MINIMUM_FOCUS_DISTANCE);
Log.i("dev", "found it! " + discoveredMinFocusDistance);
```

Comment: unfortunately this only works when launching the camera, not while it is running :/

Comment: @Fattie true, you should restart camera to update the focusing mode now :(

Comment: which is ridiculous!  whaaa!  :O

Answer (score 0):

You should set `TouchListener` to textureView and then set focus(`Kotlin`):

```
private fun setUpTapToFocus() {
    textureView.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
        if (event.action != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            return false
        }

        val cameraControl = CameraX.getCameraControl(CameraX.LensFacing.BACK) // you can set it to front                     
        val factory = TextureViewMeteringPointFactory(textureView)
        val point = factory.createPoint(event.x, event.y)
        val action = FocusMeteringAction.Builder.from(point).build()
        cameraControl.startFocusAndMetering(action)
        return true
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: thank you for your answer @Misha however, this is the same as tap to focus. I am trying to set the focus level

Comment: Yes, from what I read,I thought manual focusing meant to focus by tapping  :)